Differential equation with list of functions
Let's say I have a list formed by 2 functions dependent on the variable t.
For example:
A[t_] := {{Exp[t] + 3}, {t^2 - 5}}

I want to solve a differential equation like:
D[A[t],t]==5*A[t]

I am using DSolve in this way:
DSolve[D[A[t], t] - 5*A[t] == Array[0 &, {2, 1}], A, t]

which does not work.
The error message I get is :
DSolve: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions.

In reality, my vector is much larger, but I don't get what I should change even in this basic example.

I must be missing something. You say I want to solve a differential equation but to solve an ode means to find the dependent variable, which in your case is $A(t)$. But you already defined that at the top. So you already know what it is. So what is it you want to solve for?

Please note that due to the assignment of A, it's not possible to use DSolve. This is why Mathematica doesn't recognize any differential equations in your code.

True, I apologize for the confusion. What I am looking for is a way to tell Mathematica to solve a system of differential equation, where every solution will then form the entry of a vector. I should probably drop this question which just makes confusion and post a different one. Apologies.

No: don't make a new question. Edit this one to ask for what you really want.
